# I2C and Serial communication between devices

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, i2c, baud-rate

I am using python sockets to connect to a bluetooth HC-05 module with my PC. I want to send music to the HC-05 by converting a wav file to a string array which will later by converted to integers ranging from 0-65535 on an arduino.  The arduino and HC-05 communicate via serial at 9600 baud.  Then those ints will be passed into a DAC via I2C.  I am wondering if there could be a memory issue sending an enormous number of strings from my PC. Is it possible the original quality of the sound will be distorted as a result of the different rates of sending/receiving data across the devices? Or will the sound signal just be delayed on the DAC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The arduino and HC-05 communicate via serial at 9600 baud.

This is going to be too low to be usable for audio.

9600 baud gives you 7680 bits of data per second. At 16 bits per sample, you're looking at a sample rate of 481 Hz, which is too low for intelligible audio. It's barely even high enough to reproduce sound at all.

You need to:

1. Increase the baud rate. Ideally you'll want at least 57600 baud, for 46 kbit/sec of data. If higher baud rates are available, use them.
2. Use fewer bits for each sample. Using 4 bits for each sample at 56 kbaud will give you a respectable sample rate of 11.5 kHz. The audio will sound a little tinny at 4 bits, but it'll be intelligible.